# How to get VPC id in Terraform module?

Tags: terraform, aws-vpc

I have a module structure like

```
module "vpc" {
source = "./modules/vpc"
}

module "prod_subnets" {
source = "./modules/vpc/modules/subnets/production"
}
```

when running am getting an error like

```
[0m on modules/vpc/modules/subnets/production/production.tf line 

    162, in resource "aws_subnet" "prod-pub-1b":
    14:22:55 162: vpc_id = [4maws_vpc.production_vpc[0m.id
    14:22:55 [0m
    14:22:55 A managed resource "aws_vpc" "production_vpc" has not been declared in
    14:22:55 prod_subnets.
```

can anyone please help ?

Comment: This error also coming while giving inside module 
17:54:27  + terraform plan -out=tfplan -input=false
17:54:28  [31m
17:54:28  [1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mUnsupported argument[0m
17:54:28  
17:54:28  [0m  on main.tf line 14, in module "ec2":
17:54:28    14:   [4mvpc_id[0m = "${module.vpc.production_vpc}"
17:54:28  [0m
17:54:28  An argument named "vpc_id" is not expected here.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the contents of your two modules I'm guessing a bit, but it looks like you have an AWS VPC declared in your `vpc` module and some subnets declared in your `prod_subnets` module and you are asking how the configuration of the subnets can get access to the VPC ID.

If so, the answer is that the `vpc` module must export the VPC ID as an [output value](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html) and then the `prod_subnets` module must accept the VPC ID as an [input variable](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html).

In your `vpc` module, you can declare a `vpc_id` output value like this, for example in a file `modules/vpc/outputs.tf`:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = aws_vpc.production_vpc
}
```

In your `prod_subnets` module you can declare a `vpc_id` input variable, for example in a file `modules/vpc/modules/subnets/production/outputs.tf`:

```
variable "vpc_id" {
  type = string
}
```

Then in your existing `modules/vpc/modules/subnets/production/production.tf` file, on line 162, change the `vpc_id` argument for the subnet to refer to that variable:

```
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id
```

Finally, you must then edit the top-level file whose source code you shared in your question to pass the value between the two modules, like this:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "./modules/vpc"
}

module "prod_subnets" {
  source = "./modules/vpc/modules/subnets/production"

  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

`module.vpc.vpc_id` means to take the value of the `vpc_id` output value from the `vpc` module.

Answer (score 1):

It should be written as:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = aws_vpc.production_vpc.id
}
```